# How to automatically fill "go to everything" [ctrl + t] with current text selection

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper-2017

When I have text selected in a VS 2017 text edit window and then hit ctrl+t to do ReSharper's 2017 Ultimate's "go to everything", the selected text is not automatically placed into the "go to everything" search field.

As automatically pasting selected text into search dialogs is pretty standard functionality, I'm hoping there is a way to configure ReSharper to do this but have not been able to find one.

Does anyone know? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try ticking the checkbox `Remember last search` on `ReSharper | Options | Environment | Search & Navigation` page. According to the WebHelp page https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Environment__Search_and_Navigation.html, that should help

> ReSharper can remember the last input that you used to find something
>   with Search Everywhere/Go to Type, Go To File, and Go to Text actions.
>   When this option is selected, ReSharper will also use your current
>   selection in the editor as the initial search query. For example, you
>   can select a file name in a string and then press Ctrl+Shift+T to
>   search for files in your solution that match this name.

Comment: Thanks - sorry for the long delay in accepting your answer.